# Change layer projection in ArcGlobe

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, 3d-analyst, arcglobe

Is there any way to reproject an individual layer within ArcGlobe? In the "Draped layers" I load the tile raster (file in GeoPackage *.gpkg format) using the "Make raster layer" tool. Then in the "Elevation layers" I add the altitude data SRTM1 (N20E092.hgt) covering the raster.  
The problem is that the draped layer in WG WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere, and elevation layer in GCS_WGS_1984! Because of this we have a wrong terrain (mountains in the ocean):
[image: GeoPackage tiles]
The correct terrain is (as an example the OpenStreetMap WMS layer is taken):
[image: OpenStreetMap WMS]
Here are spatial references for draped end elevation layers: 
[image: spatial references for draped end elevation layers]
For various reasons I can't change the projection in the original GeoPackage data. Is there any way to do this in ArcGlobe? How do I achieve the alignment of layers?

Comment: project raster tool?

Comment: @ziggy This tool transforms a raster into a new projection. This creates a new raster. I don't need new raster file...